# Error running PowerShell script with .bat

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to run a .bat file calling a shell .ps1 file. 
I've tested my script directly in powershell and there it works.
But when I run the .bat, a error occurs saying to me something like [ The string started with: (...) does not contain the terminator " ]

My .bat file:

```
powershell.exe -command "& C:\Users\I\Desktop\teste.ps1"
```

My .ps1 file:

```
$scripts = 'C:\Users\I\Desktop\Teste_0.1\Teste\Teste_run.bat', 'C:\Users\I\Desktop\Teste_0.2\Teste\Teste_run.bat','C:\Users\I\Desktop\Teste_0.3\Teste\Teste_run.bat' |%{ Start-Job –scriptblock (iex "[Scriptblock] { $_ } ")}| wait-job
```

Answer (score 0):

To call another script from powershell, I don't think you need to use -command. You should just be able to call the script directly.

```
 powershell -nol -noe C:\Users\I\Desktop\teste.ps1
```

Alternately, here is another clever way to do it.

```
@echo off
  more +4 "%~dpnx0" >> temp.ps1 && powershell -nol -noe .\temp.ps1
exit /b

$scripts = 'C:\Users\I\Desktop\Teste_0.1\Teste\Teste_run.bat', 'C:\Users\I\Desktop\Teste_0.2\Teste\Teste_run.bat','C:\Users\I\Desktop\Teste_0.3\Teste\Teste_run.bat' |%{ Start-Job –scriptblock (iex "[Scriptblock] { $_ } ")}| wait-job
```